# Are we allowed to edit a question so much that answers don't make sense anymore?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, editing, closed-questions

There may be many others that fall under this category, but for the sake of discussion, let's look at:

[Is there a scriptural basis for Out-of-India hypothesis?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/26658)

To be fair to answers written prior to the heavy edits, should we rollback such questions to the original form so that answers are in sync?

Instead of desperately trying to save their question from closure after several answers have already been posted, it would be prudent for OP to ask a separate question.

Comment: Gist of the question shouldn't be changed with edits. These questions are called "[Chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478) on SE"

Comment: Answers posted to that question became obsolete after the recent edits and reopen.

Comment: Actually the question was closed as off-topic for scientific speculation and hence OP re-framed the question to make it clear.

Comment: It would be fine to fix the question so-that it made suitable for the site. Answers can be revised accordingly if needed.

Comment: "Answers can be revised accordingly if needed." - IMO, this is unfair to answerers who spent so much time answering the previous version of the question. We should encourage users to ask new questions instead of editing the current ones too much. If I were you, I'd have rolled back the question to one of the previous versions and locked/closed the post for good. @Pandya

Comment: " this is unfair to answerers who spent so much time answering the previous version of the question." No one answered the question I was trying to ask. The answers were participating in the scientific speculation despite my intent. They were rewarded heavily by other voters even though their speculation fell outside the parameters of the site. I would call that reward enough for unhelpful answers

Comment: "No one answered the question I was trying to ask." - wouldn't be better to self-delete your question and ask a new question? That way you will be also preventing unnecessary upvotes to answers which didn't address the central part of your question. BTW, I did upvote your initial question, but after the heavy round of edits I was more confused than before :) @RubelliteYakṣī

Comment: I was told in chat it's better for the site to improve a question than to start over and try again. I got my answer via the confusion. Feel free to remove it or w/e